# How to get application language and device language separately in android?

Tags: android, localization, locale, setlocale

My device language is in English and my application language is in Italian.So how I  get the  device language and application language programmatically ?

Comment: using Locale you could set and app language

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Get system language

```
Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
```

Get app language

```
String currentLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get app language"? In case the system is set to a language not supported by the app, both will return the system language, even though the app displays in a different language.

Comment: Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage()
is deprecated

Comment: if the language is english, does it return 'English' or 'en'?

Answer (score 8):

**Kotlin - Android X:**

```
val currentSysLocale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locales[0]
val currentAppLocale = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
Log.d("sys locale","$currentSysLocale")
Log.d("app locale","$currentAppLocale")
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the correct answer: getResources().getConfiguration().locale

Answer (score 7):

To Get System Language 
Use this:

```
String DeviceLang =Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
```

And For the Application Language
Use this:

```
String AppLang = Resources.getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
```