# How to change the fontFamily attribute according to on-device language?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have 9 fonts inside my app because my app supports 3 languages, 3 fonts for every language like this

```
Arabic -> ar_light_font , ar_medium_font , ar_bold_font
English -> en_light_font , en_medium_font , en_bold_font
Spanish -> es_light_font , es_medium_font , es_bold_font
```

There are some text views that take a light font and there are some text views that take a medium font and there are some text views that take bold font.

For example, I have these text views

```
<TextView
    android:id="txt1"
    android:fontFamily="ar_bold_font" />

<TextView
    android:id="txt2"
    android:fontFamily="ar_light_font" />

<TextView
    android:id="txt3"
    android:fontFamily="ar_medium_font" />
```

If you noticed if the language of the device was Spanish then will still read from Arabic font so are there any ways to change font name from ar toes depending on the device language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43092407/11880323) using the Android APIs, but they don't seem very reliable.

The approach I use is to declare a `string` in each `strings.xml` file that tells which is the current language. Something like this:

```
<string name="app_lang">en-rGB</string>
```

(Use the convention that fits better: "en-rGB", "en-GB", "english (GB)", …)

Then, in code, have somewhere the static variables:

```
public final static String APP_LANG_EN_GB = "en-rGB";
// more languages…
```

And use it when required:

```
void someMethod() {
    String appLang = getString(R.string.app_lang);

    switch(appLang) {
        case APP_LANG_EN_GB:
            // Logic for english GB language
            break;
        case …:
            // Logic for another language
    }

    if(appLang.equals(APP_LANG_EN_GB)) {
        // Do logic for english GB language
    }
}
```